# Matlab Horzcat - Out of memory

Tags: matlab, memory

Any trick to avoid an out of memory error in matlab?
I am assuming that the reason it shows up is because matlab is very inefficient in using horzcat and actually needs to temporarily duplicate matrices.

I have a matrix `A` with size `108977555 x 25`. I want to merge this with three vectors `d`, `m` and `y` with size `108977555 x 1` each.

My machine has 32GB ram, and the above matrice + vectors occupy 18GB.

Now I want to run the following command:

```
A = [A(:,1:3), d, m, y, A(:,5:end)];
```

But that yields the error:

```
Error using horzcat
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
```

Any trick to do this merge?

Answer (score 5):

> Working with Large Data Sets.  If you are working with large data sets, you need to be careful when increasing the size of an array to avoid getting errors caused by insufficient memory. If you expand the array beyond the available contiguous memory of its original location, MATLAB must make a copy of the array and set this copy to the new value. During this operation, there are two copies of the original array in memory.

1. Restart matlab, I often find it doesn't fully clean up its memory or it get's fragmented, leading to lower maximal array sizes.
2. Change your datatype (if you can). E.g. if you're only dealing with numbers `0 - 255`, use `uint8`, the memory size *will* reduce by a factor 8 compared to an array of `double`s
3. Start of with `A` already large enough (i.e. `108977555x27` instead of `108977555x25` and insert in place:

   ```
   A(:, 4) = d;
   clear d
   A(:, 5) = m;
   clear m
   A(:, 6) = y;
   ```
4. Merge the data in one datatype to reduce total memory requirement, eg a date easily fits into one `uint32`.
5. Leave the data separated, think about why you want the data in one matrix in the first place and if that is really necessary.
6. Use [C-code](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/write-cc-mex-files.html) to do the data allocation yourself (only if you're really desperate)

Further reading: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can first try the efficient memory management strategies as mentioned on the official mathworks site : https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html

- Use Single (4 bytes) or some other smaller data type instead of Double (8 bytes) if your code can work with that.
- If possible use block processing (like rows or columns) i.e. store blocks as separate mat files and load and access only those parts of the matrix which are required.
- Use `matfile` command for loading large [variables in parts](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html). Perhaps something like this :

  ```
  save('A.mat','A','-v7.3')
  oldMat = matfile('A.mat');
  clear A
  newMat = matfile('Anew.mat','Writeable',true) %Empty matfile
  for i=1:27
  if (i<4), newMat.A(:,i) = oldMat.A(:,i); end
  if (i==4),  newMat.A(:,i) = d; end
  if (i==5),  newMat.A(:,i) = m; end
  if (i==6),  newMat.A(:,i) = y; end
  if (i>6),  newMat.A(:,i) = oldMat.A(:,i-2); end
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could make it using Gunther's suggestions, it will just occupy memory. Right now it takes more than half of available memory. So, what are you planning to do then? Even simple `B = A+1` doesn't fit. The only thing you can do is stuff like `sum`, or operations on part of array.

So, you should consider going to `tall arrays` and other related big data concepts, which are exactly meant to work with such large datasets.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html